# Rails: NoMethodError in Applications#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nomethoderror

Please note that "applications" was a poor naming convention. This is because it is a scholarship application portal.

I get the following error when I try to open the index for applications.

```
NoMethodError in Applications#index

Showing /home/zane/scholarship-application/app/views/applications/_current_user_application.html.erb where line #22 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #22):

20
21
22
23
24
25




  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= current_user.application.name %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.name %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.gender %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.date_of_birth %></td>
```

Here's what the code for that page looks like:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.role == "User" %>

<h1 class="center">Your Application</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Date of birth</th>
      <th>GPA</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>University</th>
      <th>Essay</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><%= current_user.application.name %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.gender %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.date_of_birth %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.gpa %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.address %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.state %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.university %></td>
        <td><%= current_user.application.essay %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', current_user.application %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', current_user.edit_application_path(application) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', current_user.application, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<% end %>
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Defining different roles
    enum role: [:Guest, :User, :Admin]
    #Users can only have one scholarship application
    has_one :applications
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Ability Model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        if user.role == "Admin"
            can :manage, :all
        elsif user.role == "User"
            can :manage, Application
            can :manage, User
        else
            can :read, Static_Page
        end
    end
end
```

Application Model:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    #Users may only submit one application
    validate :limit_applications, :on => :create

    #User must fully fill out all forms application
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :gender, presence: true
    validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
    validates :gpa, presence: true
    validates :university, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
    validates :state, presence: true

    private
    def limit_applications
        limit = 1
        if self.user.applications.(:reload).count >= limit
            errors.add(:base, "You can only create #{limit} application.")
            end
        end
 end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "gpa"
    t.text     "essay"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "university"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "state"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "winner"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "nasa_apis", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.integer  "role",                   default: 1
    t.boolean  "winner",                 default: false
    t.integer  "application_id"
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your `User` model?

Comment: would you mind posting your user.rb code ?. Looks like you haven't defined an 'application' relationship there or there's no method with that name in the user's model.

Comment: Updated with models!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you made a model called `application.rb`.  When you type `current_user.application`, Rails searches for a method called application.  This will only work if you specified a database association in your model to connect it to a table called applications.  I don't know what the association is, but if you're calling .application (singular), I'd imagine you need to add one of these to your User model: `has_one :application` or `belongs_to :application`.  Keep in mind you'll also need to add the corresponding database association to the Application Model.  There's also a chance that Rails doesn't like the word Application and that could just be screwing up everything.

Also, the attributes you named sound an awful lot like attributes that should belong to a user, not an application.  Is there any chance you don't need the `.application` at all and these are attributes of your user model?  That would mean writing code like `current_user.email`, not `current_user.application.email`.

Comment: I just updated it with the code from those models! What I meant is I wanted to post the current_user's application, and then the email from that application (email is a field they type in on the application)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've included more code the answer is pretty clear: change `has_one :applications` to `has_one :application`

Comment: This is the answer.  The fact that you are getting another error means this was accurate.  It seemed you updated the question with the new error, and from my understanding here is the answer to your new issue: you are getting the error because some of your users don't have an application, so calling current_user.application returns nil and you can't call .name on nil

Comment: in order to get it so that it does not raise an error, you can do current_user.application.try(:name)